# Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise (PerformancePoint) KPI using multiple data sources

Tags: sql, excel, sharepoint-2010, ssas, performancepoint

Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise (PerformancePoint) KPI using multiple data sources

I am attempting to create a KPI that uses multiple data sources, with the “actual” data coming from an analysis services cube, and the “target” data coming from either a sharepoint list or excel services data source.

The setup is dead easy, adding  multiple data sources etc. The problem comes trying to get the two data sources to correctly apply dimension or time filters.

Basically if my Excel Services data columns source looks like this:

| Date | Area | Target |

All that happens when the target data source is specified is the entire list gets summed up and put against every cell. So if the scorecard is showing area (a dimension) on rows, and a date on columns, whatever the sum total of my targets (summed on date and area) is listed as the target on every single row (and every date).

It seems to me that the dimensions specified in the actual KPI section (and the scorecard) don’t map to the other data source.

I’m wondering is what I’m trying to do possible? It seems like a great idea – the result would be management would have a really easy spread sheet they can access through sharepoint, modify targets and then save and have it updated across all the relevant KPIs.

What is the common solution for this? Do you have to get the target data into the same AS cube?